# ng-model - combine dynamic and static

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to append a static subfield to a dynamic ng-model identifier?

```
ng-model="newDevice[field.name].min"
ng-model="newDevice[field.name].max"
```

I need the "min" and the "max" as static fields. But the example did'nt work.

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'static fields'?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me. You can take a look at this plunker and see the difference from your example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/0a2TFf7GtAz8VN0JTUin?p=preview

Or you can provide a plunker of your own that shows your problem.

**Update**: In order to use `newDevice[field.name].min`, you must have an object on your scope called new device, and one of its properties must be the value of `field.name`. Otherwise you can't use ng-model as is.

Comment: When you delete "someName: {}" from $scope.newDevice it wont work. I can't set someName, because it's dynamic and I don't know it.

Comment: Then no, if you can't know which properties on the model to initialize, I don't believe it's possible with just ngModel. I've updated my answer to reflect that.